# Looking for korean text corpus

Tags: corpora, korean, resource-request

I'm looking for a list of text corpus for korean. Is there any web site where I can find it?

Regards.

Comment: Try opendata.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2):

There are a bunch of Korean corpora on this page:

http://semanticweb.kaist.ac.kr/home/index.php/KAIST_Corpus

You have to request them and get a code for downloading, and the zip format wouldn't open with the regular windows unzip program.  I had to use a Korean zip program called [bandizip](http://www.bandisoft.co.kr/bandizip/) to unzip the files.
The KAIST raw corpus has just plain hangeul text.
The "High-quality morpho-syntactically annotated corpus" was pos-tagged by hand, but has quite a few errors and inconsistencies.
The automatically-analyzed large-scale KAIST corpus was pos-tagged automatically.

Also, the 국립국어원 has a searchable corpus at https://ithub.korean.go.kr/user/corpus/corpusSearchManager.do#, but I haven't used it much.

Answer (score 2):

See a list of Korean corpora available in Sketch Engine at https://www.sketchengine.co.uk/user-guide/user-manual/corpora/by-language/korean-text-corpora/

Some of them are accessible with 30-day free trial account on Sketch Engine.

Answer (score 1):

You can try a search on the [Virtual Language Observatory](https://vlo.clarin.eu). Enter "korean" and "corpus" in the General search slit and search (600+ results) and then use the facets on the right hand side of the site to restrict language (to Korean) and resource type (to Corpus, Dataset, or Collection).

You will find both spoken and written corpora.